# Parallel execution calling a method thread safety

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

Having the following:

```
List<Person> persons = // list of persons
Parallel.ForEach(persons, (i) => {
      AddAge(i);
});

// Does this method needs to be thread safe?
// Why?
public void AddAge(Person person)
{
    // Multiple threads execute here at once. However they're  
    // working with their own "person" object, therefore    
    // each thread won't corrupt others "person" object - is this assumption correct?
    person.Age =+ 10;
}
```

- Since each person gets updated "separately" on their own separate threads and one has nothing to do with another, does AddAge() method have to be thread safe?
- Does CLR executes it's own copy of "AddAge()" per thread - making it separate between threads?

Comment: `Passed by reference` you're not passing anything by reference on that line.  Also, your `AddAge` computes a number and then drops it on the floor; it doesn't actually do anything with the number it creates (which won't compile).

Comment: Person is a reference type. So when it gets to AddAge it sends a reference to that object. does it not?

Comment: The value of the variable is a reference.  That variable is passed by value though, not by reference.

Comment: Can you please edit your code so it shows actual logic (that compiles) and that you intend to execute?

Comment: Fixed the code. now it compiles and it will update Person object

Comment: @BobSwanson No, the code doesn't compile.

Comment: Even if you ensure there is no duplicate `Person` in the list, different Person instances can have a property pointing to the same instance of another object, meaning if you change one Person object it can implicitly change another one too. The term "Thread Safety" is itself vague and used in different ways by different people, example [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe/). As for the code posted, I don't think incrementing a value type on one object in multiple threads concurrently would ever throw an exception anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread safety relates to modifying the same data from multiple threads. If you are operating on separate data (such as your `Parallel.ForEach`) and are properly gating your work so that batches are completed before dependant work you do not need thread safe code within, as you are doing your thread safety outside the method (by ensuring each thread gets its own set of data to work with).

Comment: @Guvante-"(by ensuring each thread gets its own set of data to work with)." - this means that each thread will have it's own copy of AddAge?

Comment: @BobSwanson what do you mane "own copy of AddAge"? Methods themselves have no instances - there is generally one copy of the code running per app-domain for each method... You may be referring to local variables (which are not shown in your sample) - than indeed local variables are per method invocation...

Comment: perfect: " local variables are per method invocation". thank you